# http request doesn't receive the whole information - C

Tags: c, sockets, http

After connecting to a server, I need to use the `GET` command to get all the information from it. I am, for some reason, not allowed to put `\r\n` after my get command, so the command I'm sending to the server is something like `GET http://somethingrandom.com HTTP/1.0`.

After sending the request to the address, I do not receive the same output that a normal `GET` from a terminal would:

[image: GET from a terminal]

To be more specific, I receive the following information:

[image: the following information]

- The http status
- Some odd data:

  - Date
  - Server
  - Last-Modified
  - ETag
  - Accept-Ranges
  - Content-Length
  - Vary
  - Connection
  - Content-Type

I think that the role of `\r\n` is to exactly ignore that information. (In this example the extra `<head>` tag information). If it has something to do with my code(most probably) I'll provide it afterwards.

Comment: have you read anything about http protocol?

Comment: Please, oh please, read about the HTTP protocol, web servers, and the architecture of the web before anything else. You do receive the same output. You just saw the http headers, because you are doing this programmatically.

Comment: of course I did..

Comment: @johnjoe Trust me, you haven't. You are dealing with HTTP headers, and asking about them. They are the backbone of the protocol. HTTP is a complex protocol, with many implications. You *NEED* to understand its messages before trying to implement it over a socket in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command you use on the terminal is actually the program `GET` which does a proper HTTP request using the Perl LWP library and gives you the response back. The `HTTP/1.0` at the end of the command you gave is actually ignored because only the URL is expected. Thus `GET` is similar to `curl` or `wget`. You can even call `GET --help` for the exact usage.

The thing you are trying do in C is to deal with HTTP without any library. In this case you have to properly read and parse the response, i.e. exactly the thing which `GET`, `curl` or `wget` commands do for you if you use these commands. To do this properly you need to understand the HTTP protocol first. While HTTP/1.0 is not the latest standard I recommend to study this first because it is the simplest one and it is still accepted by web servers. See [RFC 1945](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt) for the standard.

From reading the standard you will see, that there is a HTTP response header and body, delimited by `\r\n`. Thus, you need to take the information from the header in order to interpret the body properly. In the simplest case you can just strip the header.

Comment: thanks, Steffen, it makes sense. I really liked your answer :) btw I'm trying to implement what you said and so far I have the same output as before. I have already posted (by the time you read my message) that problem.