# GET command only body, header missing

Tags: c, sockets, http

I know that in order to skip the header info from a http request you need to use `\r\n` . I've read a bunch of questions/topic regarding this problem but there was no implementation that worked for me. For simplicity reasons, I will use the an URL with no relative path (to hardcode the GET command).
The URL that I used is `elf.cs.pub.ro` and I know that it's IP address is `141.85.227.116`.My super simplified code for this example goes bellow:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define MAXLEN 500

void send_command(int sockfd, char sendbuf[], char * expected) {
    char recvbuf[MAXLEN];
    if(send(sockfd, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0) > 0) {
      int data = recv(sockfd,  recvbuf, MAXLEN - 1, 0);
      printf("%s\n", recvbuf);
      if(strstr(recvbuf, expected) == NULL) {
        exit(0);
      }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * * argv) {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char server_ip[20] = "141.85.227.116";
    char sendbuf[MAXLEN];
    char recvbuf[MAXLEN];

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("Socket creation error.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset( & servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(80);

    if (inet_aton(server_ip, & servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        printf("Invalid IP\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
  if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr * ) & servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
      printf("Connection error\n");
      exit(-1);
  }
  //If I use "GET / HTTP1.0\r\n" the connection never ends
  //and same for "GET / HTTP1.0"...
  sprintf(sendbuf,"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");

  char expected[MAXLEN];
  strcpy(expected, "2");
  send_command(sockfd, sendbuf, expected);
  memset(recvbuf, 0, strlen(recvbuf));
  int n;
  while ((n = recv(sockfd, recvbuf, MAXLEN - 1, 0)) > 0) {
    printf("%s",recvbuf);
    memset(recvbuf, 0, strlen(recvbuf));
  }
  close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is at `sprintf` I REALLY do not know why things go wrong, even after reading RFC 1945 and the answers from the site, I still do not know why the header does not get print...

L.E. : Why negative? I'm asking a simple question for which I provided full testing code + printscreens.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are exactly expecting. But if I take your unchanged program and run it it shows me the proper HTTP response (header and body) at stdout, as I expected from reading the code - see https://pastebin.com/H101CnWz.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm using that function to compare the http status... if it starts with 2 => SUCCESS, else => PERMISSION DENIED

Comment: You cannot use `strstr` like that... it could find *any* character `2` that happens to be among the initially read values, like `Content-Length: 42`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm expecting [this](http://imgur.com/a/G5p97) , instead of [this](http://imgur.com/a/nHR6L) . I want to simulate a `GET` command from terminal..

Comment: @AnttiHaapala absolutely, my code is way more different ... I did not want to copy paste the whole thing. The idea is the same :)

Comment: I guess the problem is with the `head` tag..

Comment: @johnjoe: I don't get the output you show in the first image from accessing `http://elf.cs.pub.ro`, even in the browser. What is the URL you are using to get the first output?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm using this exactly command in terminal : `GET elf.cs.pub.ro HTTP/1.0`

Comment: You did not provide screenshots in your question. There is no problem description, just "things go wrong". It's not clear what you're trying to do and why you think your code isn't doing it. In fact, there isn't even a question in there.

Comment: *I'm asking a simple question* - not really a simple question. One needs to guess a lot and know your previous question (which was already hard to understand) to deal with this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is hard to understand because it is not clear what really is expected. It makes only sense when looking at [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075552/http-request-doesnt-receive-the-whole-information-c).

In the previous question the OP executed the following on the command line (real command line, not HTTP request):

```
 GET elf.cs.pub.ro HTTP/1.0
```

This did not what the OP expected, i.e. sending a HTTP/1.0 request to elf.cs.pub.ro. Instead it used the GET command (which does a GET request using the LWP perl library) and did interpret the first argument as a URL and thus returned the content of `http://elf.cs.pub.ro`. Then it took the next argument `HTTP/1.0` and did treat this as another URL, i.e. `http://HTTP/1.0`. Specific to the environment of the user (or specifics of the GET command) `HTTP` was treated as `www.http.com`, i.e. the real URL was thus `http://www.http.com/1.0`. Thus essentially the OP did two commands (here shown with GET, but one could also use curl or wget or similar):

```
 GET http://elf.cs.pub.ro/ 
 GET http://www.http.com/1.0
```

In the code shown in this question the OP instead only does the first request. To do the second the program has to be modified for the new target host and URL.

Comment: You are so right!!! That's why from the terminal with the command `GET elf.cs.pub.ro HTTP/1.0` there was a little bit delay between the two outputs. Nice catch!

Comment: I'm expecting to see the `head`'s tag content, just as in the terminal command... I don't know how to express myself better..

Comment: @johnjoe Which one? There are two `<head>` tags because you're fetching two URLs.

Comment: also, ` GET elf.cs.pub.ro HTTP/1.0` is wrong, should be `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: elf.cs.pub.ro`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: yes and no. Host header is not required with HTTP/1.0 (but with HTTP/1.1) although you need it when using virtual hosts, i.e. multiple server names on the same IP address. In this case it works without.

Comment: In general, virtually :D nothing works without Host headers nowadays.

Comment: so.. it is still not clear... how can I solve the problem?

Comment: @melpomene the second one, the one after the `html` tag is closed.

Comment: @johnjoe That's the one from `http://http.com/1.0`. Why are you trying to access `http.com`?

Comment: @johnjoe: It is not clear what you mean with *using what Steffen said*. I suspect that you simply run the command again, which is not what I said. I said that you need to modify the URL in the program for the other URL (i.e. for `www.http.com`). And I recommend that you check with a browser or with `curl -v` what you can expect when accessing a specific URL.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I know about view sources.. and I also understand that you said..everything is so clear now.. thanks for pointing out, I could never figure out !!! It is a homework assignment they should have told us at least how these things work..

Comment: And regarding http://http.com/1.0, how can I access that information with my program? If I try to `host` the link it does not work. To which server should I send the request?

Comment: @johnjoe: The idea is the same as with the other host, i.e. determine the IP address of `www.http.com` and send a request to this site. Only this time you really need the Host header too as discussed above: `GET /1.0 HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.http.com\r\n\r\n`.